# How can you use Angular PrimeNG pTooltip to create a tooltip with a label and caption?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a tooltip from PrimeNG and I want to add a label and a caption to both be displayed with different styling in the tooltip. Is there a way I can do this using using the pTooltip? Are there any better alternatives?

Current tooltip:

[image]

Code Fragment:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="firstname" class="p-sr-only">Username</label>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" pInputText placeholder="Username" pTooltip="Enter your username">
</div>
<button pButton pRipple type="button" label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" pTooltip="Click to proceed"></button>
```

Desired Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeNG's tooltip can render HTML if you disable the `escape` attribute:

```html
<button pButton type="button" label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" pTooltip="<div>LABEL</div><br/><div>Caption</div>" [escape]="false"></button>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tooltip-demo-cbtwpl?file=src/app/app.component.html)